# Erro ao Inicializar Classe de Modelo. Erro (2693)

Tags: angular

Estou com o seguinte erro no meu código:

```
**'AlunoModel' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)**
```

Preciso criar um objeto para fazer um put em minha API, para isso criei um Model do meu objeto da API chamado AlunoModel e tentei iniciar ele da seguinte forma:

**aluno: AlunoModel = new AlunoModel();**

Preciso corrigir esse erro para prosseguir com a aplicação, esse erro é devido a alguma configuração do tsconfig ou existe uma outra forma de fazer esse código?

**alunos.component.ts**

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AlunosService } from 'src/app/services/alunos.service';
import { AlunoModel } from '../../interfaces/aluno-model';

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-alunos',
  templateUrl: './alunos.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./alunos.component.css']
})
export class AlunosComponent implements OnInit {

  aluno: AlunoModel = new AlunoModel();
  alunos: Array<any> = new Array();

  constructor(private alunosService: AlunosService) { 
    this.listarAlunos();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  cadastrar(){
    console.log(this.alunos);
  }

  listarAlunos(){
    this.alunosService.listarAlunos()
    .subscribe( alunos => {
      this.alunos = alunos;
    },
      () => {alert('Falha ao Listar Alunos!');})
  }
}
```

**alunos.component.html**

```
<h2>Alunos Cadastrados:</h2>

<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">ID:</th>
        <th scope="col">NOME:</th>
        <th scope="col">IDADE:</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let aluno of alunos">
        <td>{{aluno.id}}</td>
        <td>{{aluno.nome}}</td>
        <td>{{aluno.idade}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <h2>Cadastro de Alunos:</h2>

  <form>
      Nome: <input type="text" name="nome" [(ngModel)]="aluno.nome">     
      Idade: <input type="text" name="idade" [(ngModel)]="aluno.idade">
      <br>
      <br>
      <button type="button" (click)="cadastrar()">Cadastrar</button>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, após muitos testes...
O que estava acontecendo era que no model AlunoModel o export estava sendo feito como:

`export interface AlunoModel`

Mudei o export e o fiz como:

`export class AlunoModel`

O erro sumiu logo após a mudança...